# Bad format for date in Mysql by mysqlconnector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, date

I created a table with `mysql.connector` like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE %s (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    date VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    s_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    shukkin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    taikin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    t_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    shucchou VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    shucchou_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    shucchou_kaeri_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', 
                    PRIMARY KEY (ID))" %val_s
```

And I'm trying to insert there and date `now` with this code block

```
   now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
   now = now2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

but when I insert to `date VARCHAR(200)` it becomes something like this

```
   0.000742942050520059
```

And I dont know where is a problem... I tried inserting directly like this `06/04/2019` but when I selected * from table it shows same number as above.
Can someone please tell me where is a problem?

```py
now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = now2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        now_t = now2.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    # For showing image of above  settings --OPTION--
        # show the output image
        #cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        #cv2.waitKey(0)

        # SQL for "shukkin"
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='ninsho', user='root', password='0308', unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock")
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            valler = name.copy()
            val_s = valler.replace(" ", "")
            stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%s'" %val_s
            cursor.execute(stmt)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result:
                print("je")
                dates = now
                # print ("date=", dates, "now=", now)
                # Check if there is record from today ("shukkin")
                query = "SELECT date FROM %s WHERE date = %s AND shukkin = %s" % (val_s, dates, str("'"+name+"'"))
                try:
                    # print("rorororo")
                    cursor.execute(query)
                    myresult = cursor.fetchall()
                    # print(myresult)
                    for x in myresult:
                        #print("ttt")
                        a = x[0]
                        print(a)
                        if a == now:
                # If there is record from today - Update it
                            names.set(name + "さん" + "\n" + "エラー：もう登録済")
                            memo.set("今日はすでに出勤を登録しました")
                # If there is no record from today - Create it
                        else:
                            now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
                            now = now2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                            val = name
                            val_s = val.replace(" ", "")
                            sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO `%s`(`date`, `s_time`, `shukkin`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (val_s, now, now_t, name)
                            cursor = connection.cursor()
                            result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
                            connection.commit()
                #print ("Record inserted successfully into table")

                except:
                    print("except")
                    now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
                    now3 = now2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                    val = name
                    val_s = val.replace(" ", "")
                    sql_insert_query2 = "INSERT INTO `%s`(`date`, `s_time`, `shukkin`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (val_s, now3, str("'"+now_t+"'"), str("'"+name+"'"))
                    print(val_s, now3, now_t, name)
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query2)
                    print("except2")
                    connection.commit()
            else:
                print("nieje")
                val = name
                val_s = val.replace(" ", "")
                query = "CREATE TABLE %s (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL default'{}', s_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', shukkin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', taikin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', t_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', shucchou VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', shucchou_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', shucchou_kaeri_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL default'{}', PRIMARY KEY (ID))" %val_s
                cursor.execute(query)
                myresult = cursor.fetchall()
                gettr()


        except mysql.connector.Error as error :
            connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
            #print("Failed inserting record into table {}".format(error))
        finally:
            if(connection.is_connected()):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                #print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are doing the insertion into this table?

Comment: @rdas added it above

Comment: Don't  store dates as varchar, you have date, datetime, timestmap data types in MySql

Comment: Using a `varchar` field to store dates is a bug in itself. Use a proper date type instead. Once you fix that bug, you can easily pass date values as strongly-typed date parameters in a parameterized query

Comment: Don't use `%` formatting to create queries. It will leave you open to SQL injection.

Comment: what formating should I use?

Comment: Indeed, using `query = "SELECT date FROM %s WHERE date = %s AND shukkin = %s" % (val_s, dates, str("'"+name+"'"))` to create a query by string formatting leaves you wide open to both SQL injection attacks *and* the conversion errors described in this question

Comment: @MarcelKopera **no formatting** at all. Use parameterized queries instead, and *don't* store dates as strings. In fact, your desired string format makes it impossible to order the data by date or search by date ranges. `12/01/2000` will always come before `01/01/2019`.

Comment: Anyways, if you are using varchar to store dates in %m/%d/%Y format, you never need a varchar(200), because your date is going to be 10 char long. You should change are your table structure to fit dates and times correctly